# Regex match WordPress wp-config configurations

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm trying to replace some content in the wp-config with regex but I can't get it to work.

Here is my regex pattern:

```
(?=DB_NAME', ')(.*?)(?<='\);)
```

And here is a snippet of the config:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username_here');
```

The idea is to replace database_name_here.
And the php:

```
$configContent = preg_replace("/(?=DB_NAME', ')(.*?)(?<='\);)/", $databaseName, $configContent);
```

The result is this:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('database-name

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username_here');
```

So the pattern doesnt work. But I don't know how to fix it. Why is the lookarounds included in the group?

The reason I don't use str_replace and replace database_name_here is because I will use this in multiple languages. And database_name_here is translated in other languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have swapped the order of look-ahead and look-behind.

```
"/(?=DB_NAME', ')(.*?)(?<='\);)/"
```

should be:

```
"/(?<=DB_NAME', ')(.*?)(?='\);)/"
```

Comment: Yes of course. It reads from left to right so ahead means before it matches... Quite obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
$configContent = preg_replace("/(?=DB_NAME', ')(.*?)(?='\);)/", $databaseName, $configContent);
//                                            here ___^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$configContent = preg_replace(
    '/define\([\s]*[\'"]DB_NAME[\'"][\s]*,' .
    '[\s]*[\'"][^\'"]*[\'"][\s]*\)/i',
    "define('DB_NAME', '{$databaseName}')",
    $configContent);
```

Comment: It is helpful to briefly describe what your solution does and/or how it works.